# How to write csv to mysqldb without error in Python?

Tags: python, csv, mysql-python

I have got a csv file, which one i want to write into a MYSQLdb with Python 2.7.
I already did this with another csv file, and it worked correctly, but here i get an error message about the query.cursor?!

Error message:

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/air18.py", line 84, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 221, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 107, in _warning_check
    warnings = self._get_db().show_warnings()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 371, in show_warnings
    self.query("SHOW WARNINGS")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 282, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")
```

Here my code:

```js
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='1234',
    db='database')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ 
   CREATE TABLE `airline` (
  `A` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `B` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `C` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `D` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `E` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `F` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `G` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"""
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='1234',
    db='database')
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ load data local infile 'C:/Python27/output.csv' 
into table airline
character set latin1
fields terminated by ';'
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n';
ignore 1 lines;
"""
cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

The "create table" part is running, but the second part when i want to upload it with the csv file not working.

My csv file:

```js
"apple apricot";" avocado";"blackcurrant (fruit)-";"blackberry";"blueberry (fruit) ";"";"lemon lime"
"quince pear";" banana";"papaya (fruit)-";"orange";"passion fruit (fruit) ";"";"pineapple watermelon"
```

Comment: `lines terminated by '\r\n';` must precede `ignore 1 lines;`.

Comment: I corrected it, but the error message is the same

Comment: You have _**two**_ Semicolon, use only one at the end.

Comment: No, i haven't got.
My csv file is the next:

"apple apricot";" avocado";"blackcurrant (fruit)-";"blackberry";"blueberry (fruit) ";"";"lemon lime"
"quince pear";" banana";"papaya (fruit)-";"orange";"passion fruit (fruit) ";"";"pineapple watermelon" (i write this in the question too)

Comment: Double check, `lines terminated by '\r\n';` ends with Semicolon.

Comment: Oh my god..i hate these little mistakes :D Thank you!!!!